# addValueChangeHandler of gxt ComboBox only fired on focus on another field

Tags: gwt, gxt

I have form with several GWT GXT 3 fields, one of which is a combo box.

When the combo box changes it should call a doSomething method.

My problem is that the onValueChange is only fired when I focus on another form field.
I would like that it changed just when I select  an item of the combo box.
How can I do it?

This is part of my code.

```
final ComboBox<DropDownItemDTO> field = new ComboBox<DropDownItemDTO>(storeCombo, propsTitoliRioComboItemDTO.label());
...
field.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<DropDownItemDTO>() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<DropDownItemDTO> event) {

                if (event.getValue()!=null) {
                    value.setFieldValue(event.getValue().getValue());

                } else {
                    value.setFieldValue("");
                }


                doSomething(event.getValue().getValue());

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using SelectionHandler, which fires right away on selection

```
field.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<DropDownItemDTO>() {

            @Override
            public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<DropDownItemDTO> event) {
```